# compare two csv files for unique entries

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am currently working for a newspaper distribution company and need to compare the customer data in our system to the customer data provided by the Newspaper publisher. Both sets of data come in the format of CSV, I need to find customers that are in one CSV and not in the other, a customer that's in our CSV but not in the publisher's CSV would mean we are delivering papers without getting paid. Which is something we obviously want to know.

Both CSVs contain columns such as surname, first name, address, the number of newspaper required for each day of the day.

As I mentioned above, I just need to run some sort of script to list all customers that are only in either of the CSV but not in both, as well as customers that are in both CSV but are receiving differing amount of papers(ie. receiving weekend papers only on our database but are receiving weekday papers on the other database.)

I have been using excel to do this, merge both sets of data onto one page and sort by surname then manually delete the matching customers.

To further complicate things, 1/10 high street and unit 1, 10 high st are the same thing, but I don't know if it's possible to have this sort of fault tolerance built in, I was thinking of ignoring the street number and only have the script look at street name, surname, and number of deliveries received.

Here is a sample of our CSV:

```
                                      sun   mon tue wed thu fri sat
JACKSON JANET     3 LONG COURT          1   1   1   1   1   1   1
JACKSON NICHOLAS  26 HERITAGE Court     1   1   1   1   0   1   1

JACKSON CHRIS     36/8 POTT Circuit     0   0   0   0   1   1   1
```

Here is a sample of the publisher's CSV:

```
                                      sun   mon tue wed thu fri sat
JACKSON J         3 LONG CRT            1   1   1   1   1   1   1
JACKSON NICHOLAS  26 HERITAGE Crt       1   1   1   1   1   1   1
JACKSON MICHAEL   44 BRENTWICK DR       1   0   0   0   0   0   0
JACKSON CHRIS     Unit 36,8 POTT Cct    0   0   0   0   1   1   1
```

I am hoping the script can ignore Janet and Chris even though the data don't match exactly, highlight Nicholas(due to the missing thursday paper) and Michael (due to him not being in both CSVs)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, etc. Please familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Those are not CSV format (Comma Separated Values).